# What is the current Pandora TLS Fingerprint for Pianobar Running on the Raspberry pi?

Tags: internet, radio

I have loaded the current version of pianobar but I need the current TLS fingerprint from Pandora to establish a connection.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 26th, 2016, the TLS fingerprint is

> FC2E6AF49FC63AEDAD1078DC22D1185B809E7534

It can be discovered by running `openssl s_client -connect tuner.pandora.com:443 < /dev/null 2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint | tr -d ':' | cut -d'=' -f2` on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I had this problem too and just solved it!

The above command didn't work for me because it return SHA1 instead of HEX-encoded fingerprint.

See my thread here: [Where can I get the current TLS_FINGERPRINT for pandora (pianobar)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/130506/where-can-i-get-the-current-tls-fingerprint-for-pandora-pianobar)