# Where can I get the current TLS_FINGERPRINT for pandora (pianobar)?

Tags: raspbian, bash

I've ran into this issue twice this month, where my auth would fail due to the `TLS_FINGERPRINT`.

The first time, I found the key online on a forum. Now, I can't find the updated key anywhere. I've tried getting it from this command:

```bsh
openssl s_client -connect tuner.pandora.com:443 < /dev/null 2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint | tr -d ':' | cut -d'=' -f2
```

But the key that returns doesn't work...

Comment: Is it because the output, `SHA1 Fingerprint=EB:F0:3C:1F:BD:AA:12:23:23:6B:27:D8:7C:CF:35:34:C8:00:F0:15` has `Fingerprint=` and what you're giving the fingerprint to only wants the actual fingerprint?

Comment: The output of the above command returns `EBF03C1FBDAA1223236B27D87CCF3534C800F015` and that's the same format as previous fingerprints I've set for pianobar.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution!!! The issue is that the tls_fingerprint in the command in my question returns a SHA1 format, but needs to return a HEX-encoded format! Found this piece of information in the man pages here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pianobar

So, after looking at how to format SHA1 to HEX, I came up with this command (and it works!)

`openssl s_client -connect tuner.pandora.com:443 < /dev/null 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $3}' | base64 -d | md5sum -b | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/../&:/g' | sed 's/://g'`